# Build is failing on Xcode 11 beta app using Cordova or AEMM

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

My build is failing on the Xcode 11 beta, The same code is working on the Xcode 10. I am using Cordova-iOS Github forked at my side as AEMM-iOS.

Basically, in AEMM-iOS, there is some customization for my app in some files and that is around 3 years old updates.

These changes are in files/folders

- CordovaLib
- bin
- package.json

So what I have tried till now

- I have replaced old CordovaLib folder in my project from the new Cordova-iOS new cloned project *--Same error*
- Also tried to replace the bin folder as well with CordovaLib folder - Some configuration error, so I replaced again it with the old one.
- Added the AEMM-iOS my commits to the new Cordova-iOS project file and used in my project. *--Same error*

So can you please let me know, what I am missing, or what can I try to resolve the below error.

Thanks in advance!!!!

> Error: Error code 1 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/devra/Desktop/AEM/xcode-beta-working/viewer-ios/CordovaPlugins/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,CordovaPlugins.xcodeproj,ARCHS=x86_64 i386,-target,CordovaPlugins,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=x86_64 i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/devra/Desktop/AEM/xcode-beta-working/viewer-ios/CordovaPlugins/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/devra/Desktop/AEM/xcode-beta-working/viewer-ios/CordovaPlugins/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch